# Little bit confusing to compute time complexity of nested loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

```
1 for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
2    for(j=1; j<=n; j*=2){
3      a[i][j]=b[i][j-1]+1;
4    }
5 }
```

line 1 : n+1 times

lnie 2 : n/2+1 times

line 3 : constant time c

so, I computed $(n+1)(n/2+1)c=(n^2+2n+2)/2+c=\theta(n^2)$

Is it right computation?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Please note [our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) that explains in detail how to analyse algorithms like this rigorously.

Comment: On line 2, you have `j*=2` rather than `j+=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line $2$ is executed for $j=1,2,4,\cdots 2^k$ where $k$ is such that $2^k\le n<2^{k+1}$. Hence, taking the logarithm

$$k\le\log_2n<k+1$$or

$$k=\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor.$$

So the total time is

$$n\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor c=\Theta(n\log n).$$